# How do I add [1] to an array?

Tags: processing.js

```javascript
var months = ["jan", "feb"];
```

I am using processing.JS

```javascript
 var mouseClicked = function(){
     if(mouseX < 78 && mouseX > 12){
  months = months + 1;
     }
```

gives me j. 
How do I make it so that it goes from jan to feb and so on?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say it "gives you j"?

Comment: It outputs.. You see, I was using an editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a separate **index variable** which you add 1 to. Something like this:

```javascript
var index = 0;
var months = ["jan", "feb"];
var mouseClicked = function(){
  if(mouseX < 78 && mouseX > 12){
    index = index + 1;
   }
}

var monthName = months[index];
```

More info is available in [the Processing.js reference](http://processingjs.org/reference/Array/).

Comment: GREAT! Thanks a ton for your help!